# AWS cli command to list all the IAM users with last activity for than 180 days ago

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

what aws-cli command should i execute to list all IAM users whose account had last activity more than 180 days ago.

Basically we have to filter all those resources so that we can delete their accounts later

Comment: Not the answer that you want, but CloudTrail is the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

See [How to find unused credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_finding-unused.html).

Specifically with the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), use a combination of:

- `aws iam list-access-keys` to get information about the access keys for a given user
- `aws iam get-access-key-last-used` to see when a given access key was last used

Comment: What about console access?

Comment: @Kutzi you can [use CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-aws-console-sign-in-events.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Check the script I wrote for the purpose for 90 days. You can change the parameter to 180 days and run it. Additionally, you would need to pass the AWS profile parameter from the ~/.aws/credentials file.
[IAM_Access_Keyage](https://github.com/VinayakGadad/AWS-Scripts/blob/master/AWS-IAMLegacyKeys/iam_access_keyage)

Comment: The script also only checks access via access keys and not console access as far as I can see